# Find the interior of $A\cup B$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Find the interior of $A\cup B$, where $A=\{(x,y):x\in\mathbb{Q},y^2\geq{x}\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):x\notin\mathbb{Q},y\geq{x^2}\}$

---

If we let $y=f(x)$, $A\cup{B}$ will look a continuous function

The interior will be a line joining on the points tgt create by $\mathbb{Q}$ and complement $\mathbb{Q}'$, which are $f(\mathbb{Q}\cup\mathbb{Q}')$, right?

Comment: Isn't it $y\ge x^2$ on both places? And you wanted to consider the graph of $f(x)=x^2$, didn't you?

Comment: no, first one is $y^2\geq{x}$ and the second one is $y\geq{x^2}$ are confirmed.

Comment: I ask whether this was a homework problem. Beyond that, if you’re looking for your set to look like (the graph of) a function of any sort, you’re barking up the wrong tree. First you should draw a picture of the two sets while ignoring the condition of $x$’s membership in $\mathbb Q$. Then see how the ignored conditions restrict or constrain the membership of the two sets.

Comment: Then what is $f$? And how do you mean '$A\cup B$ will look a continuous function'?

Comment: @Berci, I let $y=f(x)$ in the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** As Lubin suggested in a comment, draw both $A_0:=\{(x,y)|y^2\ge x\}$ and $B_0:=\{(x,y)|y\ge x^2\}$, then conclude that  ${\rm int}(A\cup B)={\rm int}(A_0\cap B_0)$.